# Wrong date inserted into database Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, date

[image]

Sometimes, somehow wrong date is inserted into `expires_at` column.

As you can see in the attached picture, I got creation date of the token and expired date (+3 days from `created_at`). Sometimes occasionally `expires_at` is not +3 days but +few seconds, minutes.

And php code is simple as that:

```
public function createToken($user, $expiresIn = '+3 days')
{
    $token = new Token();
    $token->setUser($user);
    $token->setExpiresAt(new \DateTime($expiresIn));

    $manager = $this->getManager();
    $manager->persist($token);
    $manager->flush();

    return $token;
}
```

Can somebody explain me, why `expires_at` has not +3 days sometimes but +few seconds/minutes?

Comment: It depends on the argument you passed to the `createToken` method.

When you just give one argument, `$user` "+3days" is automatically assigned to $expiresIn parameter. But when you give another parameter, it pass this value to `$expiresIn`.
Where do you call your method?

Comment: Shooting in the dark here, have you checked the server time? maybe there is something fishy there.

Comment: what values are you getting for $expiresIn? +3 days, is a default value you set - meaning if $expires in isn't set, it will be +3 days inside method, otherwise it is goign to be whatever it is being set during method call.